# How do I get Chrome Canary as my default browser and not Google Chrome

Tags: macos, google-chrome, browser, default-settings, google-chrome-canary

How do I get Chrome Canary as my default browser? Should I delete my Google Chrome browser or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

Go to your mac's System preferences > General > and select Google Chrome Canary in the default web browser section.